# nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:92

Tags: nginx, ssl

I can't find my problem...

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  domain.net;

        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;


        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
#        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
#        location = /50x.html {
#            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


   # HTTPS server
   #
   server {
       listen       443 ssl;
       ssl on;
       server_name  domain.net;

       ssl_certificate      /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem;
       ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/privkey.pem;

       ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
       ssl_session_timeout  5m;

       ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
       ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

       location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_redirect off;
       }
   }

}
```

when I command

```
 sudo service nginx restart


* Stopping Nginx Server...                           [fail]
* Starting Nginx Server...
 nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:92
                                                     [fail]
```

line 92 is

```
# HTTPS server
#
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    ssl on;
    server_name  domain.net;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/privkey.pem;
```

`server {` line is 92,

please some body help me..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just a typo.

Comment: @ceejayoz you solved my problem... it's my shy mistake... I will close this question, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've screwed up your commenting:

```
#        location = /50x.html {
#            root   html;
        }
```